# Cordova keyboard plugin native.keyboardopen event not fired. How to stop scrolling whilst keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm developing a cordova / angular hybrid app. I'm trying to disable the ability for the user to scroll whilst the keyboard is open.

The cordova keyboard plugin from ionic [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) provides two events, one for when the keyboard opens and another for when it closes. **The event for when the keyboard closes does not fire, ever**.

In an angular run script (app.run(function...) I am have the following snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    alert("keyboard open"); //This never fires!
    $cordovaKeyboard.disableScroll(true);
}

window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    alert("keyboard closed"); //This fires as expected.
    $cordovaKeyboard.disableScroll(false);
}
```

The event handler for 'native.keyboardshow' never fires, the 'native.keyboardhide' event fires consistently, as expected.

After some googling I came across a post saying that the App can't be run in Fullscreen mode. I added the following to my confix.xml:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
```

This I believe is the default value anyway, it made not difference, neither did setting the value to true.

Has anyone come across this? I'm using Cordova 6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register your listener to the `window` object as you already did with your `'native.keyboardhide'` event:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    alert("keyboard open"); //This never fires!
    $cordovaKeyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
```

Comment: aha! Thanks for this, can't believe I did not notice such a thing.